# Add Task and Assign to Contact with Infusionsoft PHP API

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

I'm using Infusionsoft's PHP API to add contacts - https://developer.infusionsoft.com/

In addition I'm using this framework for Infusionsoft by Novak: https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk

```
$contact = new Infusionsoft_Contact();

$contact->FirstName = $first_name;
$contact->LastName = $last_name;
$contact_name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
$contact->Email = $email;

$contact->save();
```

After the contact is added, I'd like to create a task and assign it to the newly created contact and an employee also.

```
$task_description = "Call this person asap";
$contact_id = $contact->id;
$employee_id = 2496;
```

I can't find the method in the documentation for doing this. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Infusionsoft Dev Forum, it seems you need to create a ContactAction: [see thread here](http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/19146-Function-to-Create-Task-and-Assign-to-Contact?highlight=api%20create%20task)

joeynovak mentions that the field names for the ContactAction table do not necessarily match what you think they will, so [see this thread for a good example of the field names here](http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/17874-Adding-a-Task-to-a-contact?highlight=api%20create%20task) in the first response by MichaelFairchild.

Just for reference, [in this thread on the Dev forum](http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/2873-API-Table-References-Diagram?highlight=contactaction) you'll find a link to a Table References Diagram where you will see the ContactAction table.

Also, if you run into trouble where you get a note when you are trying to create a task, I found [this thread](http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/15859-How-to-create-a-Task?highlight=contactaction) that has a code example from someone using the iSDK.

Comment: None of the links work even though I have an account with them.

Comment: It appears they have deleted the old community forum. :(  I will check my notes and see if I can find any other links.

Comment: For the ContactAction related fields, you can see this page: https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/

Comment: On that page, if you click on "ContactAction" you will see a list of all the field names for that table.    Still looking for more information for the other links I gave.